# Android: Transitioning from storing data in lists to using SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

at the moment I am using a list to store a bunch of contacts but now i'd like to use SQLite. I've read many tutorials but they all make databases from scratch and I already have a lot of code that I want to be used.

Here is how I am storing data at the moment.

```
public class NewContactActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText firstName;
    private EditText lastName;
    private EditText mobileNumber;
    private EditText homeNumber;
    private EditText workNumber;
    private EditText homeAddress;
    private EditText emailAddress;
    private EditText workAddress;
    private EditText contactNotes;
    private Button saveButton;
    private Button cancelButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_contact);

        firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        mobileNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobileNumber);
        homeNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.homeNumber);
        workNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.workNumber);
        homeAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.homeAddress);
        emailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
        workAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.workAddress);
        contactNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactNotes);
        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);

        // set listener for the save button so that when it is pressed
        // a contact added and the home screen becomes the view.
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Contact.contactList//<<<<This is a static arrayList in the contact class that is having contacts added to it
                        .add(new Contact(firstName.getText().toString(),
                                lastName.getText().toString(), mobileNumber
                                        .getText().toString(), homeNumber
                                        .getText().toString(), workNumber
                                        .getText().toString(), homeAddress
                                        .getText().toString(), emailAddress
                                        .getText().toString(), workAddress
                                        .getText().toString(), contactNotes
                                        .getText().toString()));
                HomeScreenActivity.selectedContactIndex = -1;
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                        HomeScreenActivity.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // the cancel button will just return the user to the home screen
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                        HomeScreenActivity.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

How can I use this code to add to a sqlite database instead of a list adapted to a  listview?

Comment: Please look at this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend MotoDev studio,  an eclipse plugin by Motorola.

They have a whole perspective dedicated to generate database tables. When done, you can get nicely generated ContentProviders with just a few clicks.

The ContentProviders makes it easy to add/edit/delete rows or querying for data.

I would have posted some usage examples but am currently on my mobile.